# Execute a model in codeigniter with cronjob

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, codeigniter-3

I have a codeigniter web app, and I already did a model that will do a request on a cam API to make a print screen, the script works good, here is it:

```
<?php

 class CronjobImagePrintScreenAPI extends CI_Model{
 function __construct()
 {
      // Call the Model constructor
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('curl');
      $this->load->helper('file');
 }



public function show_jobs(){
    $flag = FALSE;
    $query = $this->db->get('cron_jobs');
    $query_result = $query->result();
    if (empty($query_result)) {
    $flag = FALSE;
    }else{
    $flag = TRUE;
    }
   if($flag === TRUE){
   $datasidget = $this->curl->simple_get('myloginapi');
   $datasid = json_decode($datasidget,true);
   $data_sid =  $datasid['data']['sid'];

   $reqUrl = "myprintscreenapi";
   $imageencode = $this->curl->simple_get($reqUrl);
   $insert_id = $query_result[0]->name;
   $path = "./images/$insert_id";
   write_file($path, $imageencode, $mode = 'wb');
   $this->db->where('name', $insert_id); 
   $this->db->delete('cron_jobs'); 

    }
}
}
```

And I want to make a cron that will execute that model above once at each 1 min, I know how to do that, what I don't know is what php script I have to write in order to run that model with cron, I made a controller like this:

```
<?php
class Cronpicture extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->load->helper('url','form');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->model('CronjobImagePrintScreenAPI');
}
public function getcronjob() {
$result=$this->CronjobImagePrintScreenAPI->show_jobs();
return $result;
}
}
?>
```

But this obviously this won't work, cause something has to call call that function. Any ideas how to make a executable php file to run with cron in order to call that model function? Thanks!

Comment: I suppose your cron is running from CLI, so just follow example from [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
 php /path_to_index/index.php Cronpicture getcronjob
```

Or just do wget and use a url

```
wget -O http://yoururltoload
```